# Where does the expression "no hay tu tía" come from?

Tags: expresiones, modismos, historia, coloquialismos

In Spanish, the expression *"**No hay tu tía**"* roughly means that there's no way to do something.
However, "tía" on its own means "aunt", and "there's no aunt of yours" is kind of a... weird? way to express such a concept.

The [DLE entry for "tía"](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=ZoWtFfy) says nothing about this saying or meaning, hence my question: **where does *"No hay tu tía"* come from, and how did it end up with that meaning?**

Comment: Google "no hay tu tía" links to many webs that explain it, like https://www.muyhistoria.es/curiosidades/preguntas-respuestas/ipor-que-decimos-no-hay-tu-tiaq or https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-no-hay-tu-tia/ or https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=34366 or https://sigificadoyorigen.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/no-hay-tu-tia/  or http://www.aulafacil.com/articulos/sabias/t1922/el-origen-de-la-expresion-no-hay-tu-tia ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You won't find that in the DLE under *tía*, but under *[tutía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=azZlqGW)*. The tutía or [atutía](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atut%C3%ADa) was a healing salve used in ancient times, so *no hay tutía* means *there is no remedy for that*. Of course, *tutía* came in disuse long time ago, so nowadays nobody remembers it and the idiom evolved into *no hay tu tía*, which is quite meaningless, but at least uses familiar words.

Answer (score 15):

It is a very popular and common misunderstanding. The word originally was *tutía* or *atutía*:

> **[atutía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4MUqCuX)**
>
> Del ár. hisp. *attutíyya*, este del ár. clás. *tūtiyā[']*, y este del
>   sánscr. *tuttha*.
>
> 1. f. Óxido de cinc, generalmente impurificado con otras sales metálicas, que, a modo de costra dura y de color gris, se adhiere a
>      los conductos y chimeneas de los hornos donde se tratan minerales de
>      cinc o se fabrica latón.
> 2. f. Ungüento medicinal hecho con atutía.

The expression has its origins in the shortened form *tutía*, as is stated by the DLE itself:

> **[no hay tutía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=azZlqGW)**
>   Tb. **no hay tu tía**.
>
> > La var. *no hay tu tía*, falsa separación de *no hay tutía*, en ambos
> >     casos con el sentido figurado de 'no hay remedio', porque la tutía se
> >     empleaba con fines medicinales.
>
> 1. expr. coloq. U. para dar a entender a alguien que no debe tener esperanza de conseguir lo que desea o de evitar lo que teme.

The funny thing is that the expression soon came to be expressed as *tu tía*. There is only one case in the CORDE with *tutía*, in the form "no hubo tutía", dating from 1870. But there are several cases with *tu tía*, ranging from 1797 to the 20th century.

The reason for that is that the *tutía* remedy was obsolete from the very beginnings of the saying. Texts with the word *tutia* or *tutía* can be found in the CORDE from the 13th to the 17th centuries, but not after that date:

> *Del segundo grado del signo de capricornio es la piedra a que dizen **tutia** uerde que es llamada marina Et la minera desta es en ribera de la mar de tierra de cin. [...] Del tercero grado del signo de capricornio es la piedra de la **tutia** amariella a que llaman espannola.*
>
> Alfonso X, "Lapidario", c 1250 (Spain).
>
> ---
>
> *Quando ya las viruelas están desecadas, para que se acaven de caer y quitar, se usará del azeyte rosado o del ungüento rosado, y si uviere algo que abajar o emparejar en las voquillas y llagas, mézclese con esto dicho el ungüento blanco y litargirio, y si se usare del azeyte violado y rosado con polvos de litargirio y **tutia** preparada, con un poco de alcanphor y alvayalde, con el buen discurso del médico y conforme a la disposición del paciente, creo hará maravillosos effectos y acabará de derribar las viruelas, y emparejará el rostro quitando los hoyos y señales que tuviere.*
>
> Manuel de Escobar, "Tratado de la esencia, causa y curación de los bubones y carbuncos pestilentes", 1600 (Spain).

Answer (score 4):

To complete [Gorpik's](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22812/1674) and [Charlie's](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22813/1674) excellent answers, let's check what [Google Ngram Viewer shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no%20hay%20tu%20t%C3%ADa%2Cno%20hay%20tut%C3%ADa&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20hay%20tu%20t%C3%ADa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20hay%20tut%C3%ADa%3B%2Cc0) upon searching for both:

- no hay tu tía (blue)
- no hay tutía (red)

[image]

As you can see, the version of *tu tía* (blue) has gotten more hits over the years and now it is the one commonly used (despite a little peak of *tutía* out of late).

This reminds me about the expression *motu proprio*, which is usually and wrongly written as *(de) motu propio* ([Fundéu reported it](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/motu-proprio-no-de-motu-propio/)) and the graph shows how [they are nowadays used equally](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=motu%20propio%2Cmotu%20proprio&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmotu%20propio%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmotu%20proprio%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: This confirms the fact that the _tu tía_ version was popular form the very beginning.

Comment: tutía seems to be catching up